# Why does this consider the center of mass instead of the end? (RIGID BODY MOTION)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

> A uniform rod of length L and mass M is free to rotate on a frictionless pin passing through one end. The rod is released from rest in the horizontal position. 
>   What is its angular speed when it reaches its lowest position?

I don't understand why we use the center of mass, since this object is constrained by the pivot, wouldn't it be correct to use L instead of 1/2 L?

I got w = sqrt(6g/L) instead of w = sqrt(3g/L)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you use L/2 instead of L is because when you are using conservation of energy to convert the potential energy to kinetic energy, not all of the mass in the rod changes position by L. However, if you sum the energy contributions from each part of the rod, you will find that on average the decrease in height is L/2.  For each part of the rod a distance $dl$ from the center of the rod that contributes slightly more energy, there is a piece at $-dl$ that contributes slightly less energy, the average of the two being equal to a contribution at L/2.