# Energy and Center of mass

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics

A uniform rod of length L and mass M is attached to a wall by a hinge at its base. Its initial position is horizontal. Why is the initial potential energy of the rod

$U = Mg\frac{L}{2}$,

that is, we use its center of mass to calculate U. Why can't we use the other end of the rod to calculate the energy?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculte energy (or any ither magnitude) in antoher point of your rod. However, if moment of inertia ($I$) is involeved, you'll have to use [Steiner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) in order to take into account that you are calculating your magnitude outside center of mass

Comment: But why do I have to do that? Suppose I want calculate the work done by gravity on the rod. Why do I consider the torque by gravity to be acting on the center of mass, when in fact, is acting all over the rod?

Comment: I just found a question through this other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/why-does-this-consider-the-center-of-mass-instead-of-the-end-rigid-body-motion?rq=1  which is essentially the same. can you mark mine as duplicate, please.